# Empty values in return for ctypes pointer to int array

Tags: ctypes

I'm currently trying to interface the following library (http://sol.gfxile.net/escapi/) using ctypes but I"m unsure if I'm doing something wrong or the library isn't working as I expect (sample c applications seem to work)

There is a struct that you are meant to pass to `initCapture` that looks like this

```
struct SimpleCapParams
{
  /* Target buffer. 
   * Must be at least mWidth * mHeight * sizeof(int) of size! 
   */
  int * mTargetBuf;
  /* Buffer width */
  int mWidth;
  /* Buffer height */
  int mHeight;
};
```

This is my current code:

```
from ctypes import cdll, Structure, c_int, POINTER, cast, c_long, pointer

class SimpleCapParams(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("mTargetBuf", POINTER(c_int)),
        ("mWidth", c_int),
        ("mHeight", c_int)
    ]

width, height = 512, 512
array = (width * height * c_int)()
options = SimpleCapParams()
options.mWidth = width
options.height = height
options.mTargetBuf = array

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('escapi.dll')
lib.initCOM()
lib.initCapture(0, options)
lib.doCapture(0)
while lib.isCaptureDone(0) == 0:
    pass

print options.mTargetBuf

lib.deinitCapture(0)
```

However all the values in mTargetBuf are 0.  Am I calling this wrong or something else going on?

This is a C++ example of what I need to do (without the ASCII): https://github.com/jarikomppa/escapi/blob/master/simplest/main.cpp

Comment: The example passes `&capture` because the prototype is `int initCapture(unsigned int deviceno, struct SimpleCapParams *aParams)`. So `options` has to be passed by reference, not by value, e.g. `lib.initCapture(0, ctypes.byref(options))`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense but still seems to return 0. Doing options.mTargetBuf.contents returns `c_long(0)`

Comment: You need to check whether `initCapture` failed, i.e. whether it returns 0. Also, you can use `array` instead of `options.mTargetBuf`, which is safer since the array is sized. Using `options.mTargetBuf[i]` allows you to read beyond the array and potentially segfault.

Comment: `initCapture` returns 1 and the camera light comes on. I will check out `array`

Comment: Still no luck it seems.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the help `byref` helped and seems I had mistyped one o the variables in my struct and ctypes just eats the attribute error.

Comment: All ctypes types have a dict to be able to add arbitrary attributes, which can be useful, but it can also mask typos. If you want, you can define `__slots__ = ()` in the class definition, to have `options.height = height` raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @eryksun thanks good to know.

Answer (score 2):

So seems I should check my code :)

`options.height = height` should be `options.mHeight = height` as per my structure.

The `byref` also helped.

Working code:

```
from ctypes import *

width, height = 512, 512

class SimpleCapParms(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("mTargetBuf", POINTER(c_int)),
        ("mWidth", c_int),
        ("mHeight", c_int),
    ]

array_type = (width * height * c_int)
array = array_type()
options = SimpleCapParms()
options.mWidth = width
options.mHeight = height
options.mTargetBuf = array

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('escapi.dll')
lib.initCapture.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(SimpleCapParms)]
lib.initCapture.restype = c_int
lib.initCOM()

lib.initCapture(0, byref(options))
lib.doCapture(0)

while lib.isCaptureDone(0) == 0:
    pass

print(array[100])

lib.deinitCapture(0)
```